# How to prevent overlapping two bootstrap styled divs which can re-size and drag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created two divs which can drag and re-size. I used bootstrap to style these two divs. The code is fine and I can drag and re-size two divs finely. But these two divs are overlapping. What is the thing that I do incorrectly? Here is my code.

```js
   $('.draggable-handler').mousedown(function(e){
  drag = $(this).closest('.draggable')
  drag.addClass('dragging')
  drag.css('left', e.clientX-$(this).width()/2)
  drag.css('top', e.clientY-$(this).height()/2 - 10)
  $(this).on('mousemove', function(e){    
    drag.css('left', e.clientX-$(this).width()/2)
    drag.css('top', e.clientY-$(this).height()/2 - 10)
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
  })
})

$('.draggable-handler').mouseleave(stopDragging)
$('.draggable-handler').mouseup(stopDragging)

function stopDragging(){
  drag = $(this).closest('.draggable')
  drag.removeClass('dragging')
  $(this).off('mousemove')
}
```

```css
@media (min-width: 600px) and ( min-height: 600px) {
    
         .panel{
             background-size: cover;
             max-width: 1000px;
             margin-left: 10px;
             margin-right: 10px;
             margin-top: 10px;
             max-height: 1000px;
             cursor: move;
             resize: both;
             background-color: #E6E6FA;
         }
         
         .panel-body{
             background-color: #E6E6FA;
             background-size: cover;
         }
         
       }

      .resizable{ 
          overflow: hidden;
          resize:both;
          background-size: cover;    
      }
      
      .draggable{
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 100;
      }
      
      .draggable-handler{
          cursor: pointer;
      }
      
      .dragging{
          cursor: move;
          z-index: 200 !important;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
  <title>Replayable widget</title>
      
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
    
</head>
    
<body>

<div id="div1_panel" class="panel panel-primary resizable draggable"  >
    <div class="panel-heading draggable-handler">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><b>Div1</b></h3>
    </div>
    
    <div class="panel-body">
        <b>Hi, I'm div1</b>
    </div>
</div>

    
<div id="div2_panel" class="panel panel-primary resizable draggable"  > 
    <div class="panel-heading draggable-handler">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><b>Div2</b></h3>
    </div>
    
    <div class="panel-body">
        <B>Hi, I'm div2</B>
    </div>
</div> 
   
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set both divs `position:absolute` in the class `.draggable`. That's why both divs are at the left-top corner (`left: 0px`, `top: 0px`). A solution would be to add the style  `position: absolute;` not before the dragging starts, i.e. at the `mousedown` event.

e.g.:
https://jsfiddle.net/m3rg34qm/

All I have done in the fiddle is

- removed `position: absolute` from the `.draggable` class
- added `drag.css('position', 'absolute');` inside of the `onmousedown` handler
- assigned a static width to the container `.panel`

Comment: Can you please explain it little bit more?

Comment: Thanks... :) another small question... why I can't drag div one on to the div2?

Comment: because of the z-index of the div